# How do I add the iPhone SDK 3 to the latest version of Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I just upgraded Xcode, but now I don't have any 3.x SDK for Simulator. How do I add it for testing purposes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368376/testing-in-ios-3-1-3-with-the-latest-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using old versions of XCode (with previous simulators) but the most reliable one is using a device. The iPhone1's latest OS version is 3.1.3. I'm sure you can pick one pretty cheap on eBay or similar.

You will also need to make sure that you drop the minimum OS version to 3.0.

Comment: 1. Is it possible to just download the SDK 3.x and install it into the latest version of Xcode (which I currently have installed) instead of downloading an older version of Xcode? 2. If I get the device, will I be able to test `NSURLConnection` on it w/o an AT&T contract?

Comment: 1) No.  2) You can use any older device with WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

You can goto Project->Edit Project Settings, and from there edit the "Base SDK" to what ever version you have.  From here when you build and run you should be running whatever sdk simulator or device you picked.

Answer (score 0):

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html

This will show you how to install older version of xcode to run iphone simulatr pre-4.0.