# What's the latest version of Xcode that comes with iPhone SDK 3.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, download, xcode3.2

Reviewing the [iOS Developer Downloads & ADC Program Assets](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/22.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.8.3.3.1), I think it's Xcode 3.2.4, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Note that Apple is rather arbitrary about which versions of xcode you can use to submit apps to the app store.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I believe you are mistaken. They are rather picky on the SDK version though.

Comment: @Till - That could be, but I haven't unbundled the environment from the compiler/libraries, I just use them as delivered.

Comment: @KevenDTimm right, that is the way to go anyways - I was kinda nitpicking - forgive me :D ... @MattDiPasquale In case you plan to release anything on iTunes, do not use anything below iOS SDK 4.3 (at the moment).

Comment: Just thought I'd add that from any semi-recent stats I can find, any version under 4.0 is used by less than 5% of users. I finally got to dump support when I found this link, among a few more isolated studies (single apps and such) http://insights.chitika.com/2011/just-in-time-for-ios-5-ios-3-almost-dead/

Comment: @JesseNaugher, cool, yeah, I want to only support iOS 4 and above, but they want support for iOS 3.2 & up. :) It sucked at first... but the positive is that it's been a great learning experience, and I'll be able to apply many of the things I've learned to still support iOS 4 once 5 is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode 3.2.4 comes with iOS SDK 3.2. It gives options for iPad Simulator 3.2 but not iPhone Simulator 3.2 (only 4.0 & 4.1). It may allow you to build 3.2 on an iPhone device though. I just confirmed this by downloading & installing it. I think it's the latest, although Xcode 3.2.5 might also have iOS SDK 3.2, but I highly doubt it because [How do I add the iPhone SDK 3 to the latest version of Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492966/how-do-i-add-the-iphone-sdk-3-to-the-latest-version-of-xcode) suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I have an XCode 3.2.6, which I strongly believe is the latest version of Xcode 3, after which, Xcode4 is your only option

Here's the link
http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792

Comment: Actually, he is asking for iOS SDK 3.2 and your link points to 4.3

Comment: hmmm, quite possible. but in the body of the question, its mentioned **I think it's Xcode 3.2.4** so, I am not sure if matt was looking for the iPhone SDK or XCode.

Comment: I want the iPhone SDK 3.2. But, since you must install Xcode to get the SDKs it comes with, I want the most recent version of Xcode that comes with the iPhone SDK 3.2.