# iOS SDK migration

Tags: xcode, sdk, migration

Recently i've installed Snow Leopard and  xCode 3.2.5 with iOS SDK 4.2
And now i need to add previous sdk version (3.1.2) that was in my Leopard. I have mac-partition with old OS. What is the best way to do such migration? I have iphone_sdk_3.1.2_with_xcode_3.1.4_*leopard*_9m2809 image. When i launch it, it offers to install developer tools wich includes xCode of erlier version.

a little addition to my question. if I set iphone_sdk_3.1.2_with_xcode_3.1.4_*leopard*_9m2809 that does not give me an option NOT to install xCode 3.1, will I get an downgrade from xCode 3.2.5 to 3.1.2?

Comment: Why do you want to use the old SDK?

Comment: when i open Project Settings in xCode, there is only one sdk available in Base SDK list - 4.2. So i can't set SDK fo build target

Comment: You don't need to install old stuff. What you need to do is to set you Base SDK target to 3.1.2 or other and set your deployment target to the latest one and then you will be able to run your old projects in the latest Xcode. See Matt Good answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932129/iphone-simulator-3-x-not-listed-after-upgrading-to-xcode-3-2-3-beta4-with-os-4-0

Comment: didn't i say clear enough? i have only ONE option in BaseSDK list. and this option is 4.2. may be the solution is to copy some dirs like /Volumes/mac/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs?

Comment: Apple will only accept applications built using the current SDK. To support older OS versions, change the iPhone OS Deployment Target build option for your target.

Comment: i'm afraid you're wrong. i submitted iOS application built in 3.1.2 to appstore for several times and they had not been rejected. I know about build option for my target. you don't read my question at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the following link will help you in installing OLDER SDK (Device/Simulator) in order to test iphone apps on OLDER versions (for example my iPhone 2G works only up to 3.1.3)

http://chris-fletcher.com/2010/08/28/howto-install-iphone-sdk-2-0-3-1-for-xcode-3-2/